# How do I identify and remove a special character from a string in ADF or SQL?

Tags: t-sql, unicode, azure-data-factory

I have a file being extracted in an unusual format, it comes through as a text file, however it appears there are spaces between each of the characters. I have some SQL to clean this up, but when I try to import it using ADF it identifies these additional spaces as an unusual character I have never seen before.

Example of what I see in ADF :

Above is a snapshot I have taken of how it appears in ADF when I preview the inputs. I would like to just replace the symbol that appears to read 'bul' but I have no idea what these are and I am unable to copy and paste the symbol as everything reads it either as a space or not at all.

So far I have tried to enter the codes for bullet points in a replace function within ADF, when attempting to just run the file into SQL I get only blank rows currently too, so I believe this character is breaking my import too.

Any help you can offer is appreciated, I'm really at my wits end on this one.

edit:
After a prompt from Dump Eldor here is an image of the file from Notepad++. It looks like it says nul between each character. Is this a utf-16 issue?

[Notepad Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXNzj.png)

Comment: the spaces characters  appears seems to me the the file is encode as 'utf-16' where for each character there will be always a byte the symbol the the table to look for it. can you send image for the bytes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok solved it. If I encode this to UTF-16BE then it cleans itself up nicely! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue was my original file is sent as UTF-16BE encoding instead of UTF-8.

I was able to get Data Factory to read it in the correct format and all the issues are gone!